# dynogels always tells me Invalid schema content even when using examples from it's github repo

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, joi, dynogels

I'm trying to use [dynogels](https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels) as an ORM for DynamoDB, but I can't get even the simplest example to work.  No matter what I do typescript throws "Invalid schema content" error the moment I try and use it.

**Run Command**

```
ts-node main.ts
```

**main.ts**

```
import * as Dynogels from "dynogels";
import * as Joi from "joi";

// this comes out of an example on the dynogels github page
var BlogPost = Dynogels.define('BlogPost', {
  hashKey : 'email',
  rangeKey : 'title',
  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    title   : Joi.string(),
    content : Joi.string(),
    tags   : Dynogels.types.stringSet(),
  }
});

console.log("this doesn't work")
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflowpost",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dynogels": "^9.0.3",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.4",
    "dynogels": "^9.1.0",
    "joi": "^17.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

When I run I get

> StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:740
> throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
> ^
> Error: Invalid schema content:
> at Object.exports.assert (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:740:11)
> at Object.exports.schema (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/cast.js:55:10)
> at internals.Object.keys (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/types/object/index.js:352:35)
> at Object.exports.schema (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/cast.js:36:29)
> at internals.Object.keys (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/types/object/index.js:352:35)
> at Object.exports.schema (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/cast.js:36:29)
> at internals.Object.keys (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/types/object/index.js:352:35)
> at Joi.validate (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/lib/schema.js:121:71)
> at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:666:20)
> at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/Users/stephencuzzort/Projects/StackOverflowPost/node_modules/dynogels/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:139:23)

Why do I keep getting this even when I use an example from the github page?  How could I make this example work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.  It was a `joi` version mismatch.

You need to either make sure the `joi` versions match exactly, or import from the dynogels node_modules

> import * as Joi from "dynogels/node_modules/joi";

fixed it for me.